# Hiding the layout of a select box

Tags: html, layout, drop-down-menu

I need to hide the standard layout of a select box without disabling it, because I have a background image for it. The effect I want is similar to the "-webkit-appearance: none", which works but I need it to work on Firefox and IE.

How could I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such style for `IE`. For `Firefox` you can use `-moz-appearance`.

See: http://help.dottoro.com/lcglsvea.php

Comment: Seems like it should've worked, but somehow it didn't. Maybe it's the browser version? I'm on Firefox 7.0.1. Any other way to do this?

Comment: In https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS:-moz-appearance is mentioned ,that it should work ,if `version >= 1.0`